# How to check cluster working between two different JBoss Server

Tags: jboss, load-balancing, hornetq

I configured cluster between two different JBoss server using Multicast method.

Both server will be connected , when I start both JBoss server.

After  one days , I'm getting following messages
Errors start to show for the clustering in server.log

```
05:28:17,447 ERROR [org.hornetq.core.server] (Thread-11905 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-377807954)) HQ224037: 
    cluster connection Failed to handle message: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
    Cannot find binding for d7c1004f-b1a1-4160-8888-c38175ac45d599cf0dfe-5f30-11e4-bd7e-556a35fb9ec6 on 
    ClusterConnectionImpl@538608327[nodeUUID=930dee51-5f30-11e4-9695-ef52e2a27831, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=netty, 
    factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=5445&host=172-29-250-191, address=jms,
     server=HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=930dee51-5f30-11e4-9695-ef52e2a27831]
                at org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.ClusterConnectionImpl$MessageFlowRecordImpl.doConsumerCreat 
05:28:17,411 ERROR [org.hornetq.core.server] (Thread-11439
         (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=99cf0dfe-5f30-11e4-bd7e-556a35fb9ec6-136247994-702467456)) 
         HQ224016: Caught exception: HornetQException[errorType=QUEUE_EXISTS message=HQ119019: 
         Queue already exists 7a8b46d5-a038-4efd-900e-4c041c2c121f]
         At org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl.createQueue(HornetQServerImpl.java:1811) 
        [hornetq-server-2.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
```

How to ensure cluster between two servers. Is there any procedures or any work around available?

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat provides a McastReceiverTest java client test utility- further information on its use can be located at  https://access.redhat.com/solutions/123073